# How to use the Lambda expressions with multi threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

There is a function `auto check = [](void * threadIn)->bool`.
Im trying to create 3 worker threads and each to execute `check` with a parameter `int i` and return a boolean result.

I exclude part of the code that is outside of multi threading. I want to set `bool valid` to true if the return result from three threads are true.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


#ifdef _WIN32
#  include <windows.h>
#endif

#ifdef linux
#  include <unistd.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

int a[6][6];
#define forever for(;;)

void main()
{
forever
{
    bool valid;
    /*  set input from file and set up the array */

    auto check = [](void * threadIn)->bool
    {
        bool flag=false;
        int seq = * (int *) threadIn;
        switch (seq){/*...*/}
        return !flag;
    };

    pthread_t threads[3];
    int rc;
    int i, threadids[3];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        threadids[i] = i;
        cout << "main(): creating Thread " << i << endl;
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, check, (void *)&threadids[i+1]);
        if (rc){
            cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    cout << "main(): program exiting." << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    valid = (check(1) && check(2) && check(3));
}
}
```

There are some error messages mentioning lambda expression. I am not familiar with the combination of Lambda and Multi thread.

Anyone can help me out on this please? Thanks.

Comment: why not use `std::thread`?

Comment: "There are some error messages mentioning lambda expression" - are they super-secret/eyes-only, or do you think maybe showing the error *verbatim* and the build tools creating that error would he helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, check, (void *)&threadids[i+1]);
```

`pthread_create` requires an argument of type `void * (*) ( void * )`, so the parameter type and return type are both `void *`. Your lambda should follow this signature.

```
auto check = [](void * threadIn)-> void *
{
    bool flag=false;
    int seq = * (int *) threadIn;
    switch (seq){/*...*/}
    return reinterpret_cast< void * >( flag );
};
```

Also, there are some runtime errors. You create the sequence numbers by casting (which effectively does `reinterpret_cast`), but then recover them by dereferencing:

```
    int seq = * (int *) threadIn; // Dereference of non-pointer
```

This should simply be the reverse cast, since there never was a real pointer in the first place.

```
    int seq = reinterpret_cast< int >( threadIn ); // OK
```

Likewise, you need casts on all the arguments and return values to make the final line work:

```
    valid = (check(1) && check(2) && check(3));
```

It might be easier to express this program using an ordinary function `bool valid(int)` plus an overload `extern "C" void * valid( void * )` which wraps the real function and does the casts.